# User current authentication status check endpoint with django and django rest framework

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework

How could I create an endpoint in `django-rest-framework` that would facilitate checking whether a given user was currently logged in?

The idea would be to supply the authentication token and user name, then get a response like `{"Authenticated": True}` or `{"Authenticated": False"}`.

Comment: How much of this code do you want us to write? That's a pretty open ended question - you need a serializer with at least those two given fields, then add a django rest get end point for that. Which part are you having troubles with?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this example:

## models

```
class LoggedUser(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('YourUserObject', primary_key=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user

    def login_user(sender, request, user, **kwargs):
        LoggedUser(user=user).save()

    def logout_user(sender, request, user, **kwargs):
        try:
            u = LoggedUser.objects.get(user=user)
            u.delete()
        except LoggedUser.DoesNotExist:
            pass

    user_logged_in.connect(login_user)
    user_logged_out.connect(logout_user)
```

After this you can do serialize class to retrive current loged user.